# Compiling on Ubuntu (10 or 11) 32 bits for Debian 6 64 bits

Tags: 64-bit, compiling, 32-bit, debian, cross-compilation

**Does a program compiled on Ubuntu 32 bits work on Debian 6 64 bits?**

I went googling and found:
"Normally a program compiled on a 32bit system works on a 64 also, but not the other way."

So the 32 bits -> 64 bits compatibility should not be a problem. What about Ubuntu -> Debian?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. In such cases usually dependencies may be an issue. If You install x64 system, by default it loads x64 libraries. And it may lack x32 libraries. However, usually it is no problem to apt-get necessary 32 bit libs. 
I would reccomend to write very simple program like Hello World, compile it for x32 as You wish and try to run it on Debian x64.
In my opinion this is the right point to begin.

Regards

Comment: mmmh, yes, missing librairies...indeed. Thanks a lot for your answer, really informative!